# How to slide down just one level of element 's children, not sub-level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I use this code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(this).next().slideDown()
```

of a selector :`$(this).next()`

**HTML:**

```
<li class="sub-menu two-level-collapse">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="two-level-collapse parent"><i
                            class="fa fa-line-chart"></i><span>Quản lý dữ liệu trạm</span><i
                            class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
                    <ul class="two-level-collapse">
                        <li class="sub-menu two-level-collapse">
                            <a class="two-level-collapse" id="sub-sub-a" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i></i><span>cem</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="two-level-collapse">
                                <li class="two-level-collapse"><a
                                        href='{{pathFor route='manager.csv' query='type=humid_cem'}}'>humid_cem</a></li>
                                <li class="two-level-collapse"><a
                                        href='{{pathFor route='manager.csv' query='type=temp_cem'}}'>temp_cem</a></li>
                                <li class="two-level-collapse"><a href='{{pathFor route='manager.csv'
                                                                                  query='type=rainfall_cem'}}'>rainfall_cem</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu two-level-collapse">
                            <a class="two-level-collapse" id="sub-sub-a" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i></i><span>kttvtw</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
                            <ul class="two-level-collapse">
                                <li class="two-level-collapse"><a href='{{pathFor route='manager.csv'
                                                                                  query='type=humid_kttvtw'}}'>humid_kttvtw</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="two-level-collapse"><a
                                        href='{{pathFor route='manager.csv' query='type=temp_kttvtw'}}'>temp_kttvtw</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="two-level-collapse"><a
                                        href='{{pathFor route='manager.csv' query='type=rainfall_kttvtw'}}'>rainfall_kttvtw</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu two-level-collapse">
                            <a class="two-level-collapse" id="sub-sub-a" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <i></i><span>global</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>    
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

It expands all sub-level of `$(this).next()`
Like that: [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMWT6CS9GEPP)

How can I slide down just one level of element 's children, not sub-levels?
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What do you mean by *directed children* ?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I mean just a <li> tag, not child of <li>

Comment: Did you checked my answer? Can you validate if my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh.. now I get it.

is it that what you want?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMWU6SGV4H8C

basically i added that menu are initially hidden:

```
<style>
  ul.two-level-collapse {
    display:none
  }
</style>
```

Comment: can you please check my question again. i've just updated it!

Answer (score 0):

From Your question i understand that you want to get direct children on ***li*** element, if so you might use following line

```
$(this).next().firstElementChild
```

this will give you direct child on which you can use ***slideDown()*** method.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I slide down just one level of element 's children, not
>   sub-levels?

You mean only direct descendants should slide-down, then make it

```
$(this).next().find( "> ul.children" ).slideDown();
```

**Demo**

```js
$( "a" ).click( function(e){
   $(this).next().find( "> ul.children" ).slideToggle(); //using slideToggle since slideDown is not available with jquery.
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">Clinical/Laboratory</a>
<li class="page_item page-item-29 current_page_item parent"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/">Clinical/Laboratory</a>
  <ul class="children" style="display: none;">
    <li class="page_item page-item-40 parent"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/histopathology/">Histopathology</a>
      <ul class="children" style="display: none;">
        <li class="page_item page-item-99"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/histopathology/test-page/">Test page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-42"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/bacteriology/">Bacteriology</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-46"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/packaging-guidelines/">Packaging Guidelines</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-44"><a href="http://richgc.com/dust/bmk/home/clinicallaboratory/water-quality-analysis/">Water Quality Analysis</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: that's it. can you fix my code in demo link? i have a little problem!

Comment: i just updated the demo link, the old link is not execute. Can you please give me a minute to fix that case? :D